RAM Not Released After One Batch or epoch in Google collab - why?
I'm currently training a DCGAN model on the CIFAR-10 dataset using TensorFlow/Keras, but I'm running into an issue where my system's RAM is not being released after training a single batch. Eventually, my Google Collab notebook crashes due to RAM usage reaching the system limit (16GB).
Here are the details of my setup:

Model: DCGAN (Discriminator and Generator models)
Dataset: CIFAR-10
Batch size: 128
Batches per epoch: 390
Framework: TensorFlow 2.0 with Keras API
Environment: Jupyter Notebook

Observations:

After training a single batch/epoch, I noticed that my RAM usage increases and doesn't decrease after each batch.
Even after completing one batch/epoch , my memory usage keeps growing until it eventually crashes the notebook.
I'm using a standard training loop with tf.GradientTape for backpropagation.

Question: what could be causing this memory leak issue? Why is RAM not being released after each batch or epoch, even though the model and intermediate variables should be cleared?
Additional Information:
I'm using a standard model architecture for DCGAN and a basic optimizer (e.g., Adam).
The issue persists even with smaller batches (e.g., 64 or 32).
I've also tried monitoring memory usage using psutil, and I’ve confirmed that the memory keeps increasing during training.
Any insights or suggestions for efficiently managing memory during training would be appreciated!
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1cY88etNza7SwXXxHUaqSO8xdjSUIE_6w?usp=sharing
I've tried clearing the Keras backend session after each epoch using tf.keras.backend.clear_session().

I don't think model.predict should be used on batches in a loop (in generate_fake_samples). You can try simply using model() (it's callable) instead. PS all relevant code should be in the question itself, not in external links.
